# How can I catch a syntax error in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have defined an operator `#`:

```
:- op(500, yfx, #).
```

I have written the following rules to check if a term is well-formed:

```
valid(X):- integer(X).
valid(X # Y):- valid(X), valid(Y).
```

I want to write a predicate `check/1` that would return true if its argument is valid, and false otherwise. I wrote this:

```
check(Exp):- catch(valid(Exp), error(syntax_error(_),_), fail), !.
```

It returns true when Exp is well-formed. However, it does not catch the syntax error when it is non-legal:

```
?- check(5 ## 6).
ERROR: [Thread pdt_console_client_0_Default Process] Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: [Thread pdt_console_client_0_Default Process] check(5
ERROR: [Thread pdt_console_client_0_Default Process] ** here **
ERROR: [Thread pdt_console_client_0_Default Process]  ## 6) .
```

I am using `SWI-Prolog version 7.4.1 for amd64`.

How can I catch the syntax error and make `check` return false if an error is raised?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, the issue is that `check/1` is only called *if* a valid Prolog goal is entered in the first place.

Thus, when `check/1` is already invoked, the syntax is definitely at least a valid Prolog term, even if it may not make sense from the point of view of `check/1` itself. If the syntax is *not* valid, the Prolog **toplevel** already raises an error, without even invoking `check/1`.

Hence, for more control over syntax issues, you need to **read the terms** yourself.

There are several ways to do this. An easy one is to use `read/1`. For example:

```
?- catch(read(X), Error, true).
|: check(5##6).

Error = error(syntax_error(operator_expected), stream(user_input, 8, 7, 347)).
```

In this way, you can essentially build your own toplevel, which gives you more control over such issues. See also `read_term/2` and several related predicates that help with this.

An important option in connection with such issues is `variable_names/1`: It yields a correspondence between Prolog variables and their atomic **names**, so that you can report readable bindings. This is a crucial part of the toplevel, and recent progress within ISO standardization has helped tremendously with such features. Maybe, in due time, we will be able to write portable toplevels in Prolog, usable in several systems. There are many applications that would benefit from this, yours being one of them.